# Java to match every two sequence characters between two string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, list, for-loop

I have few numeric values in my list so I need to match every two sequence numbers/characters from left to right direction.

In below `stringList` I have few records and I have to compare those records with another one which is `wordA`.

I want to match every two sequence numbers/characters, so if I entered `630102` it have to return 3rd one. If I entered `630677` it has to return 2nd one because `630677` is not present in my `stringList` but here the first `4` digit `6306` is matching with my list values.

Below is my sample code what I tried.If you have any suggestions please provide.

```
String wordA = "630102"; 
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("630507");  //1st
stringList.add("630622");  //2nd
stringList.add("6301");    //3rd
stringList.add("63");      //4th
String common = "";

int count1 = 0;
int count2 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < wordA.length(); j++) {
        if (stringList.get(i).length() > j) {
            if (wordA.charAt(j) != stringList.get(i).charAt(j)) {
                break;
            } else if (wordA.charAt(j) == stringList.get(i).charAt(j)) {
                count1++;

                if (count1 == 2) {
                    count2++;
                    count1 = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (wordA.length() > stringList.get(i).length()) {
        common = stringList.get(i);
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("common is: " + common);
```

Comment: Why do you hope it looks complicated??

Comment: what about regex, It can be more easier no?

Comment: @YCF_L: Regex? The only way I have found using Regex is as what is in my answer. Personally, I prefer the first way - iteration by characters. Do you have any better idea? I'd like to see :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically 2 elementary approaches on how to solve this:

1. **For-each iteration** over the list and each character

   You were pretty close to this one. Here you go:

   ```
   int maxLength = 0; 
   int indexOfLongestMatch = -1;
   for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {                  // Iterate the List
       String string =  stringList.get(i);
       int maxIndex = Math.min(wordA.length(), string.length());  // Compare lengths
       if (maxIndex >= maxLength) {                               // Worth to continue?
           int commonLength = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j < maxIndex; j++) {                   // Iterate characters
               if (string.charAt(j) == wordA.charAt(j)) {
                   commonLength++;                                // Any match counts
                   if (commonLength >= maxLength) {               // Check for the new max
                       maxLength = commonLength;                  // Register it
                       indexOfLongestMatch = i;                   // New index of the max
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   The index of the longest matched word in the `stringList` is `indexOfLongestMatch` (equals `2` according the same input as you have provided) and the word is `stringList.get(indexOfLongestMatch)` (`6301`).
2. **Regex**. As has been suggested here by @YCF_L, another possible way is Regex which helps you to match only the strings that have the common initial characters using the pattern:

   ```
   6?3?0?1?0?2?
   ```

   To achieve this pattern from an input, you have to replace each character `.` with `$0?`, where `$0` is any matched character matched with the dot `.`. Demonstrated at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WpvSMs/1)

   ```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(wordA.replaceAll(".", "$0?"));
   ```

   Then you just find the longest matched string and its index using one iteration over the list:

   ```
   Matcher matcher;

   int indexOfLongestMatch = -1;
   int maxLength = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {                 // Iterate the List
       matcher = pattern.matcher(stringList.get(i));             // Apply the pattern
       if (matcher.matches()) {                                  // Has a match?
           int length = matcher.group(0).length();
           if (length >= maxLength) {                            // Check for the new max
               maxLength = length;                               // Register it
               indexOfLongestMatch = i;                          // New index of the max
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   The result is the same as in the example above. `indexOfLongestMatch` is the found index.

---

Note by default the result index is set to `-1` which is not existing index in the List - it means none of the strings matched the input in the way you wanted.

Comment: What do you mean with " particular value"? Would you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to return the value, that has the most common characters with your word. This is my solution to your problem:

```
    String wordA = "630677"; 
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("630507");  //1st
    stringList.add("630622");  //2nd
    stringList.add("6301");    //3rd
    stringList.add("63");      //4th
    String common = "";

    int commonCount = 0;
    int highestCount = 0;

    for(String s : stringList)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < wordA.length(); i++) {
            if(s.length() > i && s.charAt(i) == wordA.charAt(i)) {
                commonCount++;
            }
            if(s.length() <= i || s.charAt(i) != wordA.charAt(i) || wordA.length() <= i + 1) {
                if(commonCount > highestCount) {
                    highestCount = commonCount;
                    common = s;
                }
                commonCount = 0;
                break;
            }

        }        }
    System.out.println(common.isEmpty() ? "There is no common." : "common is: " + common);
}
```

EDIT: Note, that this will always return the first String from the list, in case there are more Strings with the same amount of correct characters.

Comment: What happen if i entered 631? it will not return 63

Comment: Oh, you're right! I updated it, this should work now!!

Comment: Again this is wrong if i entered 6310 it have to return 4th one 63 instead of first one.

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to do that. It returns the first value, because it has two common characters, same as the last, but as stated below the code, it always returns the first string in this case. If this isn't the behaviour you'd like, please specify what exactly you want to achieve, as I apparently didn't fully understand it...